# How do I match components in a string math expression with unknown digits in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, matching

So I have this data array which contains math expressions as strings.

```
var data = ['1+1=?', '123*45?=5?088', '-5?*-1=5?', '19--45=5?', '??*??=302?', '?*11=??', '??*1=??', '??+??=??']
```

The question marks indicate an unknown digit, so it's part of a number. How do I split them up so that I have factors/addends, the operation, and the answer on the right side of the equation stored in an array?

This is the result that I want to get:

```
'1+1=?'            --->    ['1', '+', '1', '?']
'123*45?=5?088'    --->    ['123', '*', '45?' '5?088']
'-5?*-1=5?'        --->    ['-5?', '*', '-1', 5?']
'19--45=5?'        --->    ['19', '-', '-45', '5?']
'??*??=302?'       --->    ['??', '*', '??', '302?']
'?*11=??'          --->    ['?', '*', '11', '??']
'??*1=??'          --->    ['??', '*', '1', '??']
'??+??=??'         --->    ['??', '+', '??', '??']
```

It's tricky for me especially the one where there's a subtraction with a negative number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your try ?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of using .split() with /([+*=-])/g as my pattern but this doesn't quite get the negative numbers correctly. I'm new to regex and I didn't know what I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```regex
-?[\d?]+|[^=]
```

- `-?[\d?]+`: any combination of digits and `?` with an optional leading `-`.
- `|`: or
- `[^=]`: something not a `=`

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/XufPbm/1/)

```js
const texts = [
  '1+1=?',
  '123*45?=5?088',
  '-5?*-1=5?',
  '19--45=5?',
  '??*??=302?',
  '?*11=??',
  '??*1=??',
  '??+??=??'
];

const regex = /-?[\d?]+|[^=]/g;

const groups = texts.map(text => text.match(regex));

console.log(groups);
```

---

#### Edit

If the format is consistant, you may try this regex to get each part of the equation:

```
(-?[\d?]+)([^=\d?])(-?[\d?]+)=(-?[\d?]+)
```

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/6XGkRI/1/)

```js
const texts = [
  '1+1=?',
  '123*45?=5?088',
  '-5?*-1=5?',
  '19--45=5?',
  '??*??=302?',
  '?*11=??',
  '??*1=??',
  '??+??=??',
  '?33438-103326=410112'
];

const regex = /^(-?[\d?]+)([^=\d?])(-?[\d?]+)=(-?[\d?]+)$/;

const groups = texts.map(text => text.match(regex).splice(1));

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Ma'am/Sir this is brilliant! Using not a '=' makes much sense as I was actively trying to match the operation symbols when I tried it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi. I just found a bug about the regex. When I pass in something like '?33438-103326=410112', it only return an array of length 3 since it doesn't detect the subtraction here as an operation but as a sign of the second number. Been stuck in this for hours and I can't seem to fix it. Send help please.

Comment: @PaningningPH I updated the solution to fix the bug, please check.